# Wrong accumulative number on a JavaFX Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to build a Stacked Bar Chart using JavaFX 8 and the accumulative value of some bars are not correctly reproduced graphically.

To illustrate the problem, consider the following program, extracted [from here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/bar-chart.htm#sthref371), with a little modification to get the issue:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackedBarChartSample extends Application {

    final static String austria = "Austria";
    final static String brazil = "Brazil";
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc =
            new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 =
            new XYChart.Series<>();
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 =
            new XYChart.Series<>();
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series3 =
            new XYChart.Series<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Sample");
        sbc.setTitle("Wrong accumulative values example");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");
        xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(
                Arrays.asList(austria, brazil)));
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");
        series1.setName("2003");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(austria, 9.5));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(brazil, 10));
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(austria, 9.3));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(brazil, 10));
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(austria, 11.2));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(brazil, 10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(sbc, 800, 600);
        sbc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the bars for both, Austria and Brazil, add up 30. However, at the produced chart, the Austria's bar seems that add up less than 30.

Is there anything that I am missing?

I am using jdk1.8.0_31 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it just me or 12 + 8 + 9 = 29 so everything is ok ? ;x;x;x

Comment: I have done one last quick change aiming to make the example simpler and what I really got was embarrass me! Thanks :-). I updated the example.

Comment: So what is the actual question now? With your changes, the height of the bars is equal, as expected.

Comment: Did you execute the code? The bars of the chart have the same height? What version of jdk did you use? What OS? I updated may question with these information. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I had tested it on JDK 1.8.0_45 (and it worked, with equal height bars). I tried it on 1.8.0_25 and the bars are different heights (it looks like the decimal values are truncated to ints, somehow).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try with a newer version.